# Best way to store multiple values from multiple daily transactions

Tags: mysql

I'm currently developing a Timeclock web application which will store the date, hour, and minutes which a user logs into and out of the application via a MYSQL Database. Users can log into and out of the application multiple times per day, thus 1 user can have up to 6 transactions per day. What would be the best way to store multiple transactions such as above, in a database? I'm a web developer, and our Database Admin is currently gone for summer, so I apologize if this is a pretty easy question, but I'm confused on how to optimize the storing (and later retrieval) of multiple values in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally expect that you'd have at least the following:

`User` table: has user's `login_id` (probably literally the ID they use to login to the system), `FullName`, plus other user info (don't have enough info to know what else goes in here - department, job title, etc.). This is technically optional, but is helpful to tie logins to people's actual names.

`TimeEntry` table: user's `login_id`, `EntryTime` (probably using the `timestamp` data type), `EntryType` ("I" for login, "O" for logout - this is optional, but helpful if it's possible for login or logout values to be missing (for instance, an involuntary logout due to a power failure)); plus, other relevant values (if any).

The `login_id` makes sure the entries belong to the right user. The times give us the order in which things happened. As noted, the login/logout flag helps if an entry is missing for some reason. Not sure if this is being captured automatically or if it requires action on the user's part; missing entries much more likely with the latter. I'm assuming that, when populating the `EntryTime` column, you'll just use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`; should provide maximum available time data, and help line up very rapid login/logouts if `EntryType` can't be set. (I've captured similar data from the database end on an MS SQL Server system, and the application would usually have one login that lasted for well under a second before actually connecting for real.)

NOTE: If it's possible to have a login without a logout, `EntryType` will help you properly match the pairs you have. If you have 5 entries for a user on a given day (say, "8AM", "10AM", "1PM", "4PM", "5PM"), and no `EntryType` flag, you don't know whether the missing entry is a login or a logout, or where it falls; if that is available (["8AM", "I"]; ["10AM", "O"]; ["1PM", "O"]; ["4PM", "I"]; ["5PM", "O"]), then you can easily identify the unmatched entry, and have at least a minimum confirmed hours logged in (3 hours).

AND: remember to allow for the possibility that login and logout aren't on the same calendar day (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

What happens on the 7th session?

I suggest you simply store all sessions.  Later, when querying the table, you still have the info that someone was "doing too much work".  And/or you can just list the 'first' 6.